# Time / Date constraints in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, automation, automationstudio

I am trying to set up some automated journeys in JB and would like them to only send on specific days and within specific timeframes.

E.g.

After a lead is submitted, send an email after 5(ish) days, but only send this email on day x or y, at time between x and y.  Does anyone know how / if this is possible?

Basically i am hoping the system can bank everyone that fits the first criteria (lead submitted 4 or more days ago (sine rule was last run)) and then wait to do the send until the second criteria is met (does day and time = x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the latest updates for wait activity in August Release? it should resolve your problem - http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/release_notes/august_2017_release/journey_builder/

Comment: Although this does answer the question - to remove reliance on the link, could you put the basic overview of how this would help answer the question? This has the potential to be flagged as a 'link only' answer.

Comment: Thanks Both,  this enables a wait for a specified date, or a specified attribute, but doesn't enable a wait until an optimum send day / time of each week

Comment: If you can store the optimum send time as "Contact Data", then you can use it as an attribute to determine the wait time. you need a separate data extension linked to an attribute group which can determine the optimum time populated using a query.